# I keep getting this error "Uncaught referenceError: require is not defined " anytime i build my frontend to interact with my backend with parcelV2

Tags: node.js, express, frontend, backend, parcel

I am using parcel V2.7.1 so that i can interact my frontend script with my backend express app. I imported `axios` which is an npm package, but anytime i but anytime i run parcel and build I get and error message on the browser console stated `Uncaught referenceError: require is not defined` . I checked my bundle.js file and i find some lines with the `require` keyword. In summary anytime there is a `require` keyword in my main bundle file (bundle.js) due to an npm package import from my source file (index.js) i get the error `Uncaught referenceError: require not defined`.

I set `"browserslist": "> 0.25%`
But am not sure if that even affected anything
I also set `"engines": { "browsers":"> 0.25% }`

Please what can i do now cause am out of options.. i have read through the parcel.js documentation but nothing to help me

Answer (score 5):

Basically parcel has **ability to compile the code in both native ES module and CommonJS**.

1. If you provide **main** field in package.json then by default it will output CommonJS.
2. If you provide **module** field in package.json then it will output ES module.

***Both of these compile code for node environment and can't be run on browsers and will give error***

**Solution**

To get the code, for the browser, a good way is that to not provide **main** field in the package.json. And instead write your **target output directory in the target** field. Like this:-

```
"targets": {
    "default": {
      "distDir": "./public"
    }
}
```

Also specify the **browserlist** field to specify the browser. Here is an example of using browserlist field:-

```
"browserslist": "> 0.5%"
```

You can provide the **source directory** in source field like this:-

```
"source": "resources/script.js",
```

You can study in detail for different possible targets in [parcel documentation](https://parceljs.org/features/targets/#library-targets).

Comment: Adding "browserslist" worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing your same issue. Solved it making some changes to the **package.json** file.

As mentioned in the parcel's documentation, try to **add**, if you have not already:

```json
"targets": {
  "main": false
},
```

(https://parceljs.org/features/targets/)

Next, define `"browserslist": "> 0.25%"` or `"browserslist": "last 2 versions"` right after "targets".

**Delete** the folder where the bundled code is located and use

```bash
parcel build ./js/file/to/bundle.js --dist-dir ./path/where/folder/is/supposed/to/be
```

to generate your brand new bundled js folder without require() errors.

In the end, your **package.json** file should be like this:

```json
"name": "app-name",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "app.js",
"targets": {
  "main": false
},
"browserslist": "> 0.25%",
"engines": {
  "node": ">=16.0.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js",
  "dev": "nodemon server.js",
  "debug": "ndb server.js",
  "watch:js": "parcel serve ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js/bundled",
  "build:js": "parcel build ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js/bundled"
},
```